# Querying all fields of an Article in Apex

Tags: apex, soql, knowledge, articles

I'm a bit confused about the way Knowledge Articles work. To try them out, I've created an Article type, added a single custom field and created a draft article with some dummy data. The goal is to retrieve this article using SOQL in Apex. I manage to query some standard fields by using something like this

```
SELECT Id,Title,UrlName,Summary,KnowledgeArticleId FROM KnowledgeArticleVersion WHERE Language ='en_US' AND PublishStatus ='Draft'
```

but when I try to query the custom field, I get an error saying this field doesn't exist. What is the correct way to go about this?

Comment: Add the query you're using for the custom fields to your post.

Comment: It's the same one, it just has 'Content__c' added to the list of fields

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some digging in workbench, I found that the new article type I had created apparently functions as a queryable object itself, not as a recordtype like I had expected.

I have access to all its fields by changing the query to this:

```
SELECT Id,Title,UrlName,Summary,KnowledgeArticleId,Content__c FROM MyType__kav WHERE Language ='en_US' AND PublishStatus ='Draft'
```

Where `MyType` is the name of the type I created

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Id,Title,UrlName,Summary,KnowledgeArticleId 
  FROM KnowledgeArticleVersion 
 WHERE Language ='en_US' AND PublishStatus ='Online'
```

`PublishStatus ='Online'` it will show you only published article which is visible to community or any other place.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
KnowledgeArticle.Content__c
```

Comment: If you're not sure, it probably woud be more appropriate to comment  no ?